# Ansible limit not match with pattern

Tags: ansible, limit, ansible-inventory

I have inventory file as

```
# file: production_hosts
[my_servers]
myserver0[1:4].google.com
```

When I try to run the playbook on subset of these hosts, it gives only first and last host.

```
$ ansible-playbook -i production_hosts -l 'myserver0[1:3].google.com' yum_update_all.yaml  --list-hosts

playbook: yum_update_all.yaml

  play #1 (all): all    TAGS: []
    pattern: [u'all']
    hosts (2):
      myserver01.google.com
      myserver03.google.com
```

When I tried other way, by giving each number, it gives all.

```
$ ansible-playbook -i production_hosts -l 'myserver0[1:2:3].google.com' yum_update_all.yaml  --list-hosts

playbook: yum_update_all.yaml

  play #1 (all): all    TAGS: []
    pattern: [u'all']
    hosts (3):
      myserver02.google.com
      myserver01.google.com
      myserver03.google.com
```

Pattern similar pattern hosts will not work in limit ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ansible-playbook -i production_hosts -l 'myserver0[123].google.com' yum_update_all.yaml  --list-hosts
```

or (what you actually request):

```
ansible-playbook -i production_hosts -l 'myserver0[1-3].google.com' yum_update_all.yaml  --list-hosts
```

yield:

```
playbook: playbook.yml

  play #1 (all): all    TAGS: []
    pattern: [u'all']
    hosts (3):
      myserver02.google.com
      myserver01.google.com
      myserver03.google.com
```

Comment: I thought `range` pattern will be same in `inventory` and `limit`, but its different :)

Comment: Hi, I tried the range in 2 digits, its failing `ansible-playbook -i production_hosts -l 'myserver[16-17].google.com' yum_update_all.yaml  --list-hosts` this gives error `ERROR! Invalid host list pattern: myserver[16-17].google.com`

Comment: Because there is no sequence from 6 to 1.

Comment: Then how to give these pattern? like if I have servers from 10+, how can I give range of servers in limit ?

Comment: What about `09-10` ? or `19-20` ?

Comment: You can either figure it out yourself, or ask a new question on StackExchange.

Comment: I had a similar problem as I wanted to target `myserver9` and `myserver10` in our inventory.

I ended up just using a regex (see [Ansible - Using regexes in patterns](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_patterns.html#using-regexes-in-patterns))

`-l '~myserver(9|10).*' `